# Show that a connected 1d manifold $M$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ or $S^1$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I know there are a couple of posts where this questions has already been asked, but I did not see any proof from the following approach:

I have basically shown already that if I have two open sets that cover $M$, being each of them homeomoprhic to $\mathbb{R}$ itself, then $M \cong \mathbb{R}$ or to the circle.

So I suppose my best shot is to proceed inductively. Assume it is true for $k=n-1$ and show it is also for $k=n$. We have $U_1,...U_{n}$ open sets, and we can write $M=(U_1 \cup U_2) \bigcup_{j=3}^n U_j$. I just need to show that $(U_1 \cup U_2)$ is homemorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ and then the proof will follow using our hypothesis.

My problem is that when I proved the case for $n=2$ which I can more or less apply almost identically to this, I can only conclude that $U_1 \cup U_2$ is homeomorphic to the real line or the circle.

How can I conclude that it is necessarily homeomorphic to the real line? If convenient, I am following the steps of this short [paper](https://pnp.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/igt/eiserm/lehre/2014/Topologie/Gale%20-%201-manifolds.pdf) Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't have much faith in your induction argument: what exactly is the induction hypothesis (and what are the finitely many open sets $U_n$)?

Comment: Dear @KeeleyHoek as you suspected, that did not work out. I have rewritten the question here if you are interested in helping me out ;) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4338697/show-that-a-connected-1d-manifold-m-is-homeomorphic-to-mathbbr-or-s1