# Show that a connected 1d manifold M is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ or $S^1$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I know there are a couple of posts where this question has already been asked, but I did not see any proof from the following approach:

I have basically shown already that if I have two open sets that cover $M$, being each of them homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ itself, then $M\cong \mathbb{R}$ or to the circle.

I am following the steps of this [paper](https://pnp.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/igt/eiserm/lehre/2014/Topologie/Gale%20-%201-manifolds.pdf). Here the argument is divided in the case when $M$ is compact and when it is not. Also, I assume that the manifold has no boundary (otherwise the argument would fail anyways).

So my questions is: How does one prove the case when $M$ is compact, that it is homeomophic to a circle having proved what I mentioned? It seems that what I need is just some induction to conclude, but I am not sure how to do it. And also, could anyone give me some hints in how to finish off the proof when $M$ is not compact? Ideally, but of course not neccessarily, using the fact that I have already shown? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposition 3.1 allows you to reduce a finite cover by $O$-sets to two, using induction on the number of finite $O$-sets in a cover of $X$.

Suppose (induction hypothesis) that a space that can be covered by $n$ $O$-sets (where $n \ge 2$) can in fact be covered *also* by two $O$-sets. Then if $X= \bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1} U_i$ is cover by $n+1$ $O$-sets, replace $U_n, U_{n+1}$ by their union $U_n \cup U_{n+1}$ which is an $O$-set by 3.1. We can apply the induction hypothesis (we now have $n$ sets) and we're done. The base case $n=2$ is already trivial.

So compactness plus boundary-lessness gives a *finite* cover by $O$-sets (we cannot have one set in that cover) so the fact we just showed by induction tells us that $X=U_1 \cup U_2$ with $U_1,U_2 \simeq \Bbb R$ and we're done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Everything you said is clear, however I can not see how we conclude from it that $M \cong S^1$. If I understood correctly, you showed that a compact one dimensional manifolds without boundary are homeomorphic to the real line or a circle, right?

Comment: @Cedric You say that "I have two open sets that cover $M$, being each of them homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ itself, then $M\cong \mathbb{R}$ or to the circle". Well we're in this situation now and $\Bbb R$ is not compact so if $X$ is compact it *must* be the case that $X \simeq S^1$.

Comment: I see, you are 100% correct.  Can I ask you two more things with respect to the non compact case? I do not understand the construction of $V_i$'s, more specifically, what are the $U_k$'s. What do we know about the intersection of the $U_i$'s? I need it to show the equivalence of $V$ and $X$

Comment: @Cedric There is no construction of $U_i$'s. I just assume $X$ is covered by $n+1$ many $O$-sets. There is no $V$... You make no sense.. We prove the statement: "$\phi_n$: If $X$ can be covered by $n\ge 2$ $O$-sets it can also be covered by **two** $O$-sets" by induction on $n$.

Comment: Sorry, I am speaking about the non-compact case in the article. You proved the compact case :)

Comment: @Cedric In the non-compact space it's a completely obvious and elegant construction in the paper, using the countable open cover by $O$-sets.

Comment: Not that obvious for a begginer